# Run Gulp task before build in VS Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, gulp, less

I have a new empty .NET Core project. Can I automatically run Gulp tasks before a build in VS Code?

I can run the `styles` task manually by doing `VS Code package manager -> Tasks: Run Task -> gulp -> gulp: styles`, but when I do build it does not run.

```
/// <binding beforebuild="styles"></binding>

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpless = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    var srcfile = 'styles/Styles.less';
    var dest = 'wwwroot';
    return gulp
        .src(srcfile)
        .pipe(gulpless())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

I got this code from some tutorials online and everything works except the first line.

Is this supposed to work in VS Code or is this only a luxury of Visual Studio?

Comment: you can create a compound task, consisting of a sequence of multiple defined tasks

Comment: Ok that seems like a good idea.  But does the above code not work in VS Code?

Comment: By `dotnet build`, do you mean the console command? VSCode has no control over the terminal

Comment: But the gulpfile is is within the project so I thought maybe .NET could recognize it and run the task before the build process?  Is that not right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//In this case we’re adding the a task before other task.

gulp.task('watch', ['array', 'of', 'tasks', 'to', 'complete','before', 'watch'], function (){
  // ...
})


//And in this case we’re adding for example the browserSync task.

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function (){
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
  // Other watchers
})


//We’ll also want to make sure sass runs before watch so the CSS will already be the latest whenever we run a Gulp command.

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function (){
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
  // Other watchers
});
```

> Read this document : [Gulp for Beginners](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)